# Как получить Docker образ астралинукса CE?

Tags: linux, docker, ос, astra-linux

Не могу найти в Docker Hub, как сделать из того что они [распространяют](http://astralinux.ru/products/astra-linux-common-edition) Docker образ?

Comment: есть статья по созданию базового образа https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/. Может она будет полезна для создания astralinux образа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### предуведомление

надеюсь, вы понимаете, что программа *linux* будет той же самой, что и в используемой вами хост-системе, и если запускаемому вами процессу требуется, к примеру, та же «доверенная загрузка» именно в той реализации, которая вкомпилирована в программу *linux* из дистрибутива *astra*, то правильно функционировать он **не будет**.

#### техническое

как и для любого дистрибутива, надо создать минимальный `chroot` и из него — образ:

```
$ sudo tar -C каталог-с-chroot-ом -c . | docker import - название-образа
```

создать `chroot`, как и для любого основанного на *debian gnu/linux* дистрибутива, можно с помощью скрипта *debootstrap* (входит в одноимённый пакет во многих, даже не основанных на *debian gnu/linux*, дистрибутивах):

```
$ sudo debootstrap выпуск каталог-где-будет-создан-chroot ссылка-на-репозиторий
```

docker-овцами подготовлен скрипт-обёртка вокруг *debootstrap*. там делаются docker-специфичные оптимизации, но основную работу, конечно, выполняет сам оригинальный скрипт:

```
$ wget https://github.com/moby/moby/raw/master/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap
```

в качестве `выпуска` надо указать `orel`. нужный для *debootstrap* конфигурационный файл можно взять непосредственно из пакета *debootstrap* из репозитория дистрибутива — https://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/current/orel/repository/pool/main/d/debootstrap/

в качестве репозитория надо указать http://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/current/orel/repository

вот, собственно, и всё.

#### для удобства

набросал (на основе используемой в работе) программку для *gnu make*. запускать её имеет смысл только на *debian*-основных дистрибутивах (используется программа *dpkg-deb*), должен быть установлен пакет *debootstrap*:

```
suite = orel
repo = http://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/current/$(suite)/repository

deblink = $(shell wget -qO - $(repo)/dists/$(suite)/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | zcat | sed -rn '/^Package: debootstrap$$/,/^Filename:/{s/^Filename: //p}')
debname = $(notdir $(deblink))

script = debootstrap
scriptlink = https://github.com/moby/moby/raw/master/contrib/mkimage/$(script)
suiteconf = /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/$(suite)

all: $(suite).hash

$(suiteconf): $(debname)
    dpkg-deb -x $< undeb
    sudo cp undeb$@ $@

$(debname):
    wget -qO $@ $(repo)/$(deblink)

$(suite).hash: $(suite)
    sudo tar -C $< -c . | sudo docker import - $< > $@
    @echo "готово"

$(suite): $(script)
    if [ -d $@ ]; then sudo rm -rf $@; fi
    LC_ALL=C sudo bash $< $@ $(notdir $@) $(repo)

$(script): $(suiteconf)
    wget -q $(scriptlink) -O $@
```

в результате её работы будет создан *docker*-образ с именем `orel`:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm orel cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Astra Linux (Orel 2.11.6)"
NAME="Astra Linux (Orel)"
ID=astra
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.astra-linux.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.astra-linux.com/support"
VARIANT_ID=orel
VARIANT=Orel
VERSION_ID=2.11.6
```

всё, что будет создано скриптом в текущем каталоге (и конфигурационный файл `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/orel`), после создания образа можно удалять.

Comment: Смоленск таким образом можно задебутстрапить? У него нет реп, не знаю что подставлять в `debootstrap`

Comment: @Herrgott, ну, наверно, у вас есть, например, установочный dvd с репозиторием. используйте его: примонтируйте dvd, как схему для ссылки используйте `file`: `file:///путь/к/репозиторию`. обратите внимание на три слэша: первые два — часть схемы url-а (`file://`), а дальше абсолютный путь, который, естественно, должен начинаться со слэша.