# Как создается базовый docker-образ на основе дистрибутива?

Tags: linux, docker, контейнеры

Хочется понять что из себя представляют базовые образы ubuntu, debian, alpine (и т.п), как происходит из создание и кто этим занимается.

Мне понятно, что основа любого контейнера - это linux namespace, где ядро хост-машины монтирует отдельную rootfs, за счет чего мы имеем возможность работать в инкапсулированной структуре каталогов.

Не понятно как структура каталогов, пакеты, дефольные конфиги переносятся из, например, ubuntu в этот образ. Мы же не можем (или можем?) взять снапшот ubuntu без ядра и просто перенести его в образ.

upd. Если перефразировать вопрос по другом, то как, например, я могу снять снапшот своей системы и сделать на его основе свою версию базового образа?

Comment: Для просто переноса файлов даже специальная директива есть `COPY`

Comment: @user7860670 это понятно. Что конкретно и откуда нужно копировать?

Comment: @XYZ - мне кажется, Вы находитесь в том же заблуждении, в котором находился я некоторое время назад, пытаясб кое - что понять про докер. Возможно, Вам даже поможет тот вопрос, который я задавал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356653/ В общем, если коротко: докер-это не про виртуальную машину, это про изоляцию отдельного процесса, который и "бежит" в докер-контейнере. И этот контейнер надёжно изолирован от хостовой системы и видит только ту файловую часть, которая расположена в соответвующем "слое" докер-образа. И обычно там запущен один процесс. А на Вашей машине их бегут десятки.

Comment: @XYZ - И даже если Вы перенесёте в докер - образ все-все настройки, там всё равно будет бежать один процесс. Это ограничение можно преодолеть, но всё равно докер-образ не будет эквивалентен Вашей машине

Comment: Копируются файлы базовых образы ubuntu, debian, alpine с хоста в докер образ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/839297/178576